# Timer will not start a second time

Tags: vb.net, function, datagridview, timer

I've got a function:

```
Private Sub UpdateSch()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
        Dim i As Integer = 1
        While i = 1
            Try
                If DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 1 Then
                    DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
                End If
                Using stream As System.IO.FileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead("Z:\\SchData.txt")
                    Using reader As New System.IO.StreamReader(stream)

                        Dim line As String = reader.ReadLine()

                        While (line IsNot Nothing)
                            Dim columns = line.Split(";")
                            line = reader.ReadLine()
                            Dim index = Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
                            Me.DataGridView1.Rows(index).SetValues(columns)
                        End While

                    End Using
                End Using
                Button88.Enabled = True
                DataGridView1.CurrentCell = DataGridView1.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(colIndex)
                i = 0
            Catch ex As Exception
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
            End Try
        End While

        'Check for local updating
        If updatingSch = False Then
            DataGridView1.Enabled = False
            LockWarning1.Visible = True
            lockVar1 = 0
            LockTimer1.Start()
        Else
            updatingSch = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

And then I've got a timer:

```
Private Sub LockTimer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LockTimer1.Tick
        LockWarning1.Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Enabled = True
        LockTimer1.Stop()
    End Sub
```

The function updateSch is called at form load and whenever the file is changed.  It locks the DataGridView, starts the timer which runs for 10 sec, and then unlocks the Datagridview.  This all works on load, but when it is called again it locks and never unlocks.  The second time around the timer is never started.  (I put a break point on the "LockTimer1.Start()"  and it is executed the second time, but the LockTimer_Tick event doesn't fire after that)

Comment: Calling `LockTimer1.Enabled = True` will start the timer. Try that in place of `LockTimer1.Start()` I have had better luck with that.

Comment: What is the type of `LockTimer1`? `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` or `System.Timers.Timer` or ...?

Comment: @OneFineDay I tried using LockTimer1.Enabled = True and LockTimer1.Enabled = False instead, but I got the same results.

Comment: @IanKemp Under the properties of the timer is says "System.Windows.Forms.Timer"

Comment: @OneFineDay, I very much doubt that you have actually had "better luck" with setting the `Enabled` property rather than calling the `Start` method, given that the `Start` method simply sets the `Enabled` property and nothing else anyway.  Logically, if you explicitly want to start or stop the `Timer` then you should be calling the `Start` or `Stop` method.  The `Enabled` property should be used when you have a `Boolean` value that could be either `True` or `False` so you don't know whether you're starting or stopping.

Comment: @MikeMetzger, is there any code anywhere else that is calling `Stop` or setting `Enabled` to `False` that might be being executed before the `Tick` event is raised?

Comment: @jmcilhinney No, the only place in the entire code where the timer is stopped is in the tick event shown above.  Same goes for the start code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney, nobody asked you - keep your snide comments to yourself!

Comment: @OneFineDay, whether or not someone asked me is irrelevant.  I'm just providing accurate information.  If you have a problem with that then don't provide inaccurate information in the first place.  I'd sooner hurt your feelings than let someone else go away without a proper understanding of something so easy to correct.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Any more ideas then?

Comment: Add a constructor to your form (Public Sub New) and set a breakpoint on it.  Ensure it breaks only once.  If it breaks twice then you have a bug in your code that's very common in VB.NET.  Look at the call stack.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a soution to my problem.  For the life of me I can't figure out why my previous code won't work.  What I was able to get working was a Systems.Timers.Timer (instead of System.Windows.Forms.Timer).  My code creating the timer looks like this:

```html
Dim LockTimer1 As New System.Timers.Timer()
            LockTimer1.Interval = 10000
            LockTimer1.AutoReset = False 'Run timer only once
            LockTimer1.Start()
            AddHandler LockTimer1.Elapsed, AddressOf LockTimer1_Tick
```

And then the function LockTimer1_tick:

```html
 Private Sub LockTimer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        LockWarning1.Visible = False
        DataGridView1.Enabled = True
        Button88.Enabled = True
        Button1.Enabled = True
    End Sub
```